# is there a way to return a specified tables column titles in Python using mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get a list of column names from a table in a SQL database. For example, if my database is called "book_shop" and the table I want to return the columns is called "books".

It's just the string formatting I'm after. I've tried the following...

```
SELECT * 
from information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'book_shop' 
ORDER BY table_name,ordinal_position
```

Ive got the fetchall and executed commands but it says there's something up with my SQL syntax.

Comment: I don't get any SQL syntax error from that. Please post your Python code.

Comment: If you're only interested in the table named `books` why don't you have `and table_name = 'books'`?